# jQuery/CSS issue - Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, firebug

I have my relevant css which is as follows:

```
div.tab-container div.tab{
  min-width: 150px;
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
  background-color:#3DCCF0;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight:bold;
}
div.tab-content div[class^="tab-"]{
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

div.tab-content div[class^="tab-"].active{
  display:block;
}
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.tab').click(function(){
    var tab_id      = $(this).attr('id');
    var clickedTab  = $(this);

    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $('.' + tab_id).removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.' + tab_id).addClass( 'active' );

  });
});
```

This is a very simple system and I'm really surprised it doesn't work.

> I get an error in firebug which says: Could not convert JavaScript
>   argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]

However, if I change my CSS to use the > (direct children) symbol, it doesn't throw the error (possibly because it doesn't match anymore).

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit:

Heres a jsfiddle of it apparently working: http://jsfiddle.net/jRtsd/

Comment: Why are you adding and removing the class in the same function?

Comment: I can tidy it up later, but it would work anyway, remove the class from one tab and add it to another. The question isn't about the methodology of my crap JS code ;)

Comment: Oh...Sh** I just realised what you meant, I don't think that's the issue, but yeah you're right, that is a big flaw :P

Comment: Okay I've fixed that and the issue is still occurring. I didn't think that would be the entire issue, but thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I looked at [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRtsd/) in firefox and clicked all the tabs.  Firebug is not reporting any errors.

Comment: @RobW - You are wrong in this case. It should be a `.` since the class relates the to tab id.

Comment: Yeah I know JSFiddle isn't reporting an error, but I can't replicate it. Currently I am using jQuery 1.2.6 (can't upgrade due to drupal 6) any ideas _why_ this would happen in the first place? Anything I can check would be good.

Comment: Do you have any other code? jQuery should not be using that method with setting a class. Are you doing any sort of animation, or is there another related chunk of code setting/reading properties? [1.2.6 - code that is over 4 years old - yikes for browser support] You can link to that version in fiddle [set no js library and add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the html.

Comment: [Even after updating your jsfiddle to use 1.2.6](http://jsfiddle.net/jRtsd/3/), still no error.  Is the error message, perhaps, a red herring?  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?